# How to get recode file save as .wave file

Tags: java, ivr, vxml

I want to get save audio when vxml request sent for Ivr, I develop Ivr code like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
 <form>
    <record name="myrecording" beep="true">
      <prompt>
        Please record a message after the beep.
      </prompt>
      <filled>
        <prompt>
          You just recorded the following message: <value expr="myrecording"/>
        </prompt>
      </filled>
    </record>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

I want get msg recode and after play. how to do this question? I want to answer in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your recorded message by adding  tag with your recording var and handle the submit request using some server side code like PHP/JSP/ASPX  a PHP sample is included :
Edit: adding record.jsp which uses apache commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ 
 also record.vxml is modified to submit the data to record.jsp , record.php is kept as a reference

"record.vxml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
    <form>
        <record name="myrecording" beep="true">
            <prompt>
                Please record a message after the beep.
            </prompt>
            <filled>
                <prompt>
                    You just recorded the following message: <value expr="myrecording"/>
                </prompt>
                <submit expr="record.jsp" method="post" namelist="myrecording" enctype="multipart/form-data" />      
            </filled>
        </record>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

"record.php"

```
<?PHP
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
error_reporting (0);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
echo "<vxml version=\"2.0\">";
echo "<form id=\"main\">";
echo "<block>";
if ($HTTP_POST_FILES) {
foreach ($HTTP_POST_FILES as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $Filename) {
   if (strpos($Filename, "WINNT")) { $ServerSide = $Filename; }
   if (strpos($Filename, ".wav")) { $ClientSide = $Filename; }
  } // for each statement
  $ServerSide = str_replace("\\\\", "/", $ServerSide);
  if (!copy($ServerSide, "c:/audio-storage/temp.wav")) {
   echo "Could not save filename: " . $ServerSide;
  } // if statement
  else {
   echo "Successfully saved filename: " . $ServerSide;
  } // else statement
} // for each statement
} // if statement
echo "</block>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</vxml>";
?>
```

**record.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <vxml version="2.1">
    <form>
    <%
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = new Date();
      boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      List fileItems = null;

      try {
        fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 

      try {
        Iterator iter = fileItems.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
          String newFileName = "Recording-" + dateFormat.format(date);
          String inputFilePath = "c:/audio-storage/"+ newFileName + ".wav";
          File file = new File(inputFilePath);

          try {//Writing the wav file
            item.write(file);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    %>
    <block>
      <prompt> Audio upload complete! </prompt>
    </block>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

Comment: please answer using java, jsp, in Restful web service.